# Click "Search" on a site which is iFramed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I would actually want to create a website which has another site in iFrame. The site I'd like to create, let's say its Site A. The site which should be included will be Site B.

Site B contains a search form which I'm only showing in the iframe.

I want when people visits Site A and clicks on a search button, it should send the inserted text to Site B's search form and click on submit.

Is it actually possible if these 2 sites are in different domains? If yes, can someone please let me know how to get started with this idea?

Comment: Have you edit access to site B ?

Comment: See how SiteB's form submission works in the network panel of firebug  or chrome - and issue the request yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage) to communicate across frames in different origins.

This depends on both sites co-operating to send and receive the messages (for obvious security reasons).

---

You are probably better off just submitting a form on site a with `<form action="http://siteB.example.com" target="yourFrame">` and appropriate fields. This won't work if Site B implements protection against [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Csrf) though.

Comment: Hmm, this second option seems interesting. So basically I should create a form on Site A with the Action of Site B's URL? What did you mean by the target="yourFrame"? Also should I create the exact same form fields like Site B has, so when I submit the form it will get submitted on Site B?

Comment: *What did you mean by the target="yourFrame"?* — You want it to open in a frame, don't you?

Comment: *Also should I create the exact same form fields like Site B has, so when I submit the form it will get submitted on Site B?* — of course.

Comment: I basically want to submit Site B's form using a textbox on Site A. So its like I enter the value on Site A and it gets submitted to Site B's form.

Comment: However I also want that Site B see the USER's IP address not the Server's IP.

Comment: The request isn't coming from your server, so it wouldn't see your server's IP. (It will see your URL in the referer though).

Comment: Okay, and the "target" is still not clear for me. What should I actually insert there?

Comment: The name of the frame you are targetting.

Answer (score 0):

Make Site B so that it takes in an HTTP request and call it `searchboxvalue`. Have Site B set the value of your search box for example `siteB.php?searchboxvalue=ABC` would change the value to `ABC`. When the submit button is clicked on Site A, take the value from the search box in Site A and use it to set your iframe to `siteB.php?searchboxvalue=value`